# How to access a value defined in Project > Build Settings > Other Swift Flags?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bash

I have a value in Other Swift Flags `-DSERVER_IP=${SERVER_IP}` linked to a Build Phase > Run Script: `export SERVER_IP='ipconfig getifaddr en0'`

How do I access the value of `SERVER_IP` from a ViewController or a swift file and use it to populate a variable in swift? Something like `let currentIP = SERVER_IP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build settings use environment variables that exist at the time the build start, which is before your build phase runs. Due to this, `SERVER_IP` will be empty while Xcode is doing its the build phase (exported variables are not available to other build phases).

There is a workaround, though. You can add a new Swift file to the project, let's call it `generated-stuff.swift`, and have the run script output the information there:

```sh
echo 'let SERVER_IP="'`ipconfig getifaddr en0`'"' > MyProject/generated-stuff.swift
```

The above will generate a file like with the following contents:

```swift
let SERVER_IP="1.2.3.4"
```

You'll then be able to use the variable in your project.